# what is the correct way of dynamically accessing a specific property of a map and iterate it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I have an observable named variable$, im doing ngFor using

`*ngFor="let value of variable$ | async; let i = index;`

and this works, but when I try accessing a specific values property on iteration it tells me its undefined, im trying to do it like this

`*ngFor="let value of variable$[dynamicVariable].iterableProperty | async; let i = index;"`

but it tells me it cannot read property iterableProperty of undefined.

What would be the correct way of accessing and iterating iterableProperty in this case?

Comment: **dynamicVariable** what is the value of this ? can you update the post with sample json

Comment: I also don't get how these two code lines are related and why you think the 2nd line should do anything.

Comment: value of dynamic variable is a number from 0 to 3, all of them are populated when the subscription returns. so variable$[0,1,2,3] should all work, and if I programatically subscribe to the Observable and log these values, it works, even if I use `console.log(variable[dynamicVariable])`

Comment: Did not expect it to be that hard to understand, my apologies. With that comment do you understand?
variable$ : Observable<CustomType[]>,
CustomType has a property iterableProperty[] that is an array of objects.
dynamicVariable is the index of the currentIy inspected variable instance

Comment: You can't access a "value" of a promise or observable before subscription (or `then()` and therefore you can't before `|async` which does the subscription.

Comment: So what would be the correct way of going about this? Mapping them to another observable variable and accessing them directly through that variable?

Comment: You should resolve the variable otherwise you can't access the property  of undefined.